# Deadlock in synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, deadlock

How deadlock occurs at line 8 or 16 ?

```
 1. public class DeadlockRisk {
 2.   private static class Resource {
 3.     public int value;
 4.   }
 5.   private Resource resourceA = new Resource();
 6.   private Resource resourceB = new Resource();
 7.   public int read() {
 8.     synchronized(resourceA) { 
 9.       synchronized(resourceB) {
10.         return resourceB.value + resourceA.value;
11.       }
12.     }
13.   }
14
15.   public void write(int a, int b) {
16.     synchronized(resourceB) { 
17.       synchronized(resourceA) {
18.         resourceA.value = a;
19.         resourceB.value = b;
20.       }
21.     }
22.   }
23. }
```

Comment: There is no deadlock as read and write are not called :-)

Comment: when thread read lock the resourceA, and *Simultaneously* thread write lock resourceB, so both threads cannot lock the next resources because they have locked by each other :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deadlock can occur because the lock order is inconsistent, meaning one thread can have acquired `resourceA` and be waiting on `resourceB` while another thread has acquired `resourceB` but is waiting on `resourceA`. For example:

- T1 calls `read()`, successfully acquires `resourceA`, and is then suspended.
- T2 calls `write()`, successfully acquires `resourceB` and waits for `resourceA`.
- T1 is resumed and is waiting for `resourceB` (which will never be released by `T2`).

Neither `T1` or `T2` can progress because each is waiting on a resource the other has locked. Always have a consistent lock order:

```
public int read() {
    synchronized(resourceA) { 
        synchronized(resourceB) {

public void write() {
    synchronized(resourceA) { 
        synchronized(resourceB) {
```

(However, in the posted code there appears to be no reason to have multiple locks, as both locks are always acquired.)

Comment: He just has done exactly that. It's not at all clear what kind of an answer you're looking for here. It's the same in any scenario. If you acquire locks in inconsistent orders you risk deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Read acquires resourceA as part of the outer lock. Write acquires resourceB. This happens before either thread locks the object for the inner lock.

To continue, read needs resourceB, but write has resourceB already. Write can release resourceB as soon as it gets resourceA, but read has resourceA and can't give it up until resourceB is given to it.

As a general tip, use consistent order when locking multiple objects. Either A then B in both, or B then A in both.

Comment: @BlueDiamond Read the last sentence.